# Distance travelled on moving walkway.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am reading Manga guide to calculus. I am kind of stuck at one place. The statement says;

The moving walkway moves f(x) meters in x minutes. When measured on walkway, Futoshi travels g(x) meters in x minutes. So the total distance Futoshi travels in x minutes becomes 
h(x) = f(x) + g(x)

I don't get this I thought the distance is same its just the speed is different.  Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the speed is different, then the distance traveled during the same amount of time is different. Remember that speed is the distance per unit of time (not the most precise definition, I know). In this case, the speed of the walkway is $f(x)/x$ meters/min and Futoshi is $g(x)/x$ meters/min.

The total distance traveled in $x$ minutes would be $$\overbrace{\left(\frac{f(x)}{x} + \frac{g(x)}{x}\right)}^{\text{total speed}} \overbrace{x}^{\text{time}} = f(x) + g(x)$$.

Comment: I guess I understand but again as u said total distance travelled in x minutes would be f(x) + g(x). This is correct but statement says total distance travelled by Futoshi is f(x) +g(x) but logically travelled g(x)

Comment: This depends on the frame of reference. If your frame of reference is the walkway, then Futoshi only traveled g(x) meters. If your frame of reference is the floor (stationary), then Futoshi traveled f(x)+g(x) meters.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a flag on the walkway and stand **BY** the walkway looking at the flag moving away from you, after x minute, the flag is f(x) away from you.

If you put a flag on the Futoshi and stand **ON** the walkway looking at the flag moving away from you, after x minute, the flag is g(x) away from you.

If you put a flag on the Futoshi and you stand **BY** the walkway looking at the flag moving away from you, after x minute, the flag is f(x)+g(x) away from you.

Reference are changing here.

Answer (score 0):

Say he walks 50 m/min on regular ground.  If the walkway moves at 30 m/min and he walks on the walkway he will cover 80 m/min. The point he started will move forward with the walkway and in one minute be 30 m ahead of where it started.  At the same time, he has progressed 50 m up the walkway.